# Vlookup help in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

What I am trying to do is compare column B with column F (Being an invoice number) and column D with column J (Being a money value) and if the value exists in all  columns then maybe say YES in column M?

There will be occasions where both Column B and F do match but column D and J don’t so I would like them to highlight in red or something too.

Comment: Are these matches always on the same row, or is B:D a different data set than F:J?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you can do what you need with Conditional formatting.

I sampled some data starting in row 3.

Per your instructions I have Invoice numbers in columns B and F.

I have the corresponding dollar values in columns D and J (D being related to B's invoice number, etc).

In my data I have 3 rows of information.

1. I selected range J3:J5 and created a new Conditional Formatting rule.
2. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
3. Use this formula `=J3<>VLOOKUP(F3,$B$3:$D$5,3,FALSE)`
4. Set the fill color when it fails.

J3 equals the first dollar value of your second set of data

F3 equals the first invoice number of your second set of data

$B$3:$D$5 is the full range of your first set of data

What this formula does is check to see if J3 does not equal the invoice amount for the corresponding invoice number in the first set of data.

It will work even if the invoice numbers are in a different order.

This is my result:

[image: my result]